# Full screen slider in a column (75% width of browser)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

please see link below
http://jsfiddle.net/0td2rd7k/
also you can see the code here

```
 <div id="leftCol">
    leftCol
    </div>
    <div id="rightCol">
    rightCol
    </div>

<style>
    html, body, * {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
#leftCol {
    background:green;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 25%;
    overflow: hidden;

}
#rightCol {
   background:blue;
    position: absolute;
    left: 75%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow-y: auto;    

}
</style>
```

The green and blue columns are as tall as the browser window.
I want to put a content slider in the green column and I need
slider width = green column.width
and
slider height=green column.Height

I put the jssor fullscreen slider in green column.
You can see this slider here:
http://www.jssor.com/testcase/full-screen-slider.source.html

The height is ok (it's as tall as the browser) but I dont know how can I 
set the slider width to be as long as green column width (green column width is %75 of browser window)

Colud you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

To get the jssor slider to be 100% of the width and height of its container, use the width and height css rules:

```
#jssor {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

The markup would look something like this, where the `jssor` div is the actual `jssor` slider:

```
<div id="rightCol">
    <div id="jssor"></div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0td2rd7k/1/

Comment: The `rightCol` div is absolutely positioned away from the left side of the body element by 75% of the body. Wouldn't the width of the jssor slider overflow the whole body? As it is, I'm confused as to how the text is visible in `leftCol` in the jsfiddle. How does it work?

Comment: @thelittlegumnut The rightCol div touches the top, right, and bottom of the body, so it is implicitly sized at 25% the width of body. If you give `jssor` 100% width, it will be 100% of that 25% width. Also, I don't understand the confusion over the visibility of the text.

Comment: It's just that by default, I thought a div's width would take up 100% of it's parent's width. Are you saying that if a div is absolutely positioned without any containing an explicit `width` property, it will be "squished" to fit?

Comment: @thelittlegumnut Correct. An absolutely positioned div with without an explicit `width` property will be automatically sized so that its `left`, `top`, `bottom`, and `right` properties are all consistent. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14569936/is-it-valid-to-use-top-left-right-and-bottom-css-all-at-the-same-time-to-size) for details.

Answer (score 0):

@Maximillian Laumeister based On your answer I decided to use jssor simple-fade-slideshow instead of jssor Full Screen Slideshow and I cheged this line:

```
<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px; overflow: hidden; ">
```

to this:

```
<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; ">
```

although slider expands as I expected but the images don't changes
so I changed this part:
     
      
to this:

```
<div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
```

but no success!
here is complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>
      html, body, * {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
#leftCol {
    background:green;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 25%;
    overflow: hidden;

}
#rightCol {
   background:blue;
    position: absolute;
    left: 75%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow-y: auto;    

}

  </style>
        <!-- it works the same with all jquery version from 1.x to 2.x -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- use jssor.slider.mini.js (40KB) instead for release -->
    <!-- jssor.slider.mini.js = (jssor.js + jssor.slider.js) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jssor.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jssor.slider.js"></script>
     <script>

         jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

             var _SlideshowTransitions = [
             //Fade
            {$Duration: 1200, $Opacity: 2 }
            ];

             var options = {
                 $AutoPlay: true,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
                 $AutoPlaySteps: 1,                                  //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), the default value is 1
                 $AutoPlayInterval: 3000,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
                 $PauseOnHover: 1,                               //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, 4 freeze for desktop, 8 freeze for touch device, 12 freeze for desktop and touch device, default value is 1

                 $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                         //[Optional] Allows keyboard (arrow key) navigation or not, default value is false
                 $SlideDuration: 500,                                //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
                 $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 20,                          //[Optional] Minimum drag offset to trigger slide , default value is 20
                 //$SlideWidth: 600,                                 //[Optional] Width of every slide in pixels, default value is width of 'slides' container
                 //$SlideHeight: 300,                                //[Optional] Height of every slide in pixels, default value is height of 'slides' container
                 $SlideSpacing: 0,                                  //[Optional] Space between each slide in pixels, default value is 0
                 $DisplayPieces: 1,                                  //[Optional] Number of pieces to display (the slideshow would be disabled if the value is set to greater than 1), the default value is 1
                 $ParkingPosition: 0,                                //[Optional] The offset position to park slide (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), default value is 0.
                 $UISearchMode: 1,                                   //[Optional] The way (0 parellel, 1 recursive, default value is 1) to search UI components (slides container, loading screen, navigator container, arrow navigator container, thumbnail navigator container etc).
                 $PlayOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to play slide (for auto play, navigation), 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 5 horizental reverse, 6 vertical reverse, default value is 1
                 $DragOrientation: 3,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)

                 $SlideshowOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable slideshow or not
                     $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,                 //[Required] Class to create instance of slideshow
                     $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,            //[Required] An array of slideshow transitions to play slideshow
                     $TransitionsOrder: 1,                           //[Optional] The way to choose transition to play slide, 1 Sequence, 0 Random
                     $ShowLink: true                                    //[Optional] Whether to bring slide link on top of the slider when slideshow is running, default value is false
                 },

                 $BulletNavigatorOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable navigator or not
                     $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$,                       //[Required] Class to create navigator instance
                     $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                     $AutoCenter: 1,                                 //[Optional] Auto center navigator in parent container, 0 None, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
                     $Steps: 1,                                      //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
                     $Lanes: 1,                                      //[Optional] Specify lanes to arrange items, default value is 1
                     $SpacingX: 10,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                     $SpacingY: 10,                                   //[Optional] Vertical space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                     $Orientation: 1                                 //[Optional] The orientation of the navigator, 1 horizontal, 2 vertical, default value is 1
                 },

                 $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
                     $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
                     $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                     $Steps: 1                                       //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
                 }
             };
             var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);

             //responsive code begin
             //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
             function ScaleSlider() {
                 var parentWidth = jssor_slider1.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
                 if (parentWidth)
                     jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(parentWidth, 600));
                 else
                     window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
             }
             ScaleSlider();

             $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
             $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
             $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
             //responsive code end
         });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="leftCol">

    <!-- Jssor Slider Begin -->
    <!-- To move inline styles to css file/block, please specify a class name for each element. --> 
    <div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; ">

        <!-- Loading Screen -->
        <div u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
            <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity:0.7; position: absolute; display: block;
                background-color: #000000; top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
            </div>
            <div style="position: absolute; display: block; background: url(img/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;
                top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Slides Container -->
        <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
            <div>
                <img u="image" src="img/landscape/02.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u="image" src="img/landscape/03.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u="image" src="img/landscape/04.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u="image" src="img/landscape/05.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u="image" src="img/landscape/06.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u="image" src="img/landscape/07.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u="image" src="img/landscape/08.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u="image" src="img/landscape/09.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u="image" src="img/landscape/10.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u="image" src="img/landscape/11.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--#region Bullet Navigator Skin Begin -->
        <!-- Help: http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-bullet-navigator-jquery.html -->
        <style>
            /* jssor slider bullet navigator skin 05 css */
            /*
            .jssorb05 div           (normal)
            .jssorb05 div:hover     (normal mouseover)
            .jssorb05 .av           (active)
            .jssorb05 .av:hover     (active mouseover)
            .jssorb05 .dn           (mousedown)
            */
            .jssorb05 {
                position: absolute;
            }
            .jssorb05 div, .jssorb05 div:hover, .jssorb05 .av {
                position: absolute;
                /* size of bullet elment */
                width: 16px;
                height: 16px;
                background: url(img/b05.png) no-repeat;
                overflow: hidden;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            .jssorb05 div { background-position: -7px -7px; }
            .jssorb05 div:hover, .jssorb05 .av:hover { background-position: -37px -7px; }
            .jssorb05 .av { background-position: -67px -7px; }
            .jssorb05 .dn, .jssorb05 .dn:hover { background-position: -97px -7px; }
        </style>
        <!-- bullet navigator container -->
        <div u="navigator" class="jssorb05" style="bottom: 16px; right: 6px;">
            <!-- bullet navigator item prototype -->
            <div u="prototype"></div>
        </div>
        <!--#endregion Bullet Navigator Skin End -->

        <!--#region Arrow Navigator Skin Begin -->
        <!-- Help: http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-arrow-navigator-jquery.html -->
        <style>
            /* jssor slider arrow navigator skin 12 css */
            /*
            .jssora12l                  (normal)
            .jssora12r                  (normal)
            .jssora12l:hover            (normal mouseover)
            .jssora12r:hover            (normal mouseover)
            .jssora12l.jssora12ldn      (mousedown)
            .jssora12r.jssora12rdn      (mousedown)
            */
            .jssora12l, .jssora12r {
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                /* size of arrow element */
                width: 30px;
                height: 46px;
                cursor: pointer;
                background: url(img/a12.png) no-repeat;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            .jssora12l { background-position: -16px -37px; }
            .jssora12r { background-position: -75px -37px; }
            .jssora12l:hover { background-position: -136px -37px; }
            .jssora12r:hover { background-position: -195px -37px; }
            .jssora12l.jssora12ldn { background-position: -256px -37px; }
            .jssora12r.jssora12rdn { background-position: -315px -37px; }
        </style>
        <!-- Arrow Left -->
        <span u="arrowleft" class="jssora12l" style="top: 123px; left: 0px;">
        </span>
        <!-- Arrow Right -->
        <span u="arrowright" class="jssora12r" style="top: 123px; right: 0px;">
        </span>
        <!--#endregion Arrow Navigator Skin End -->
        <a style="display: none" href="http://www.jssor.com">Image Slider</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Jssor Slider End -->


</div>
<div id="rightCol">
rightCol
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

also you can download an example here:
http://www.4shared.com/get/7hNbZf3gba/test.html

Answer (score 0):

I did it using jquery bxslider.
I did it using this code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var width = $("#leftCol").width();

        var height = $("#leftCol").height();
        $('.bxslider').width(width);
        $('.bxslider').height(height);
        $('.bximg').width(width);
        $('.bximg').height(height);
        $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
    });
</script>
```

You can see a working example here:
http://shogan.ir/
but I'm not sure it's a good way or not!
also I'm still curious how can do it using the jssor slider!